# MSBuild Filtering ItemGroup of files with condition

Tags: msbuild

This feels like it's so simple, but I cannot get it to work.

All I'm trying to achieve is a filtered list of the embedded resources.  I've tried various approaches but I can't seem to get it right.

Here's what I thought was the right solution:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <AllEmbeddedResources Include="@(EmbeddedResource)" Condition="$(FullPath.Contains('Change')"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

Edit...
To clarify, the results are without the condition, the list is all embedded resources, with the condition, the group is empty.

I've tried this inside and outside of target's, and I've tried getting the full list in one group, and then filtering in a separate group.  I know I'm just misunderstanding some fundamental part of msbuild syntax, I just can't seem to work it out.  Looking forward to being shown my stupid mistake!

Comment: `$` is for referencing properties. You want to reference metadata, which is done using `%` so for starters you should  `%(FullPath...`. But I'm 100% sure this has been asked before so just search around.

Comment: @stijn so I thought the same, but if i use this syntax [Condition="%(FullPath).Contains('Change')"] I get the error [error MSB4092: An unexpected token "." was found at character position 12 in cond
ition "%(FullPath).Contains('Change')".]  Similar questions have been asked, but whatever I do to follow their examples, it never seems to be close enough.  I'll edit to include links to what I'm tried...

Comment: @Adam do you need to do this during static evaluation (project-global) or inside a target? It is hard to do during static evaluation..

Comment: @MartinUllrich The intention is to pass the list of files to a task, to then verify some other things (p.s. inline task if it makes any difference).  I have tried it outside the target containing the task, and inside the target before the task.  Neither seems to work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Inside a target, this can be done using the batching syntax for items and using the `System.String.Copy` method to be able to call instance functions on the string:

```
<Target Name="ListAllEmbeddedResources">
  <ItemGroup>
    <AllEmbeddedResources Include="@(EmbeddedResource)" Condition="$([System.String]::Copy(%(FullPath)).Contains('Change'))" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Message Importance="high" Text="AllEmbeddedResources: %(AllEmbeddedResources.Identity)" />
</Target>
```

Note that this syntax only works inside a target and not during static evaluation (item group directly under the `<Project>` node).

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks! Happy that I wasn't just being stupid... disappointed that it's so damn obscure!

Answer (score 1):

The Condition Attribute must return a boolean, and it operates on each element of the itemgroup.
You can access each element using *%(Identity)*.
Say you have some unfiltered itemgroup called **UnfilteredItems**, and you want to filter those into a group called **MyFilteredItems**, using some regex pattern.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <MyFilteredItems Include="@(UnfilteredItems)" Condition="$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match(%(Identity),'.*\\bin\\.*').Success)"/>
</ItemGroup>
```